# Difference between Lazy<T> and LazyInit<T>

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I had the following line in a class that I was using.

```
 private static readonly LazyInit<TestClass> _instance = new LazyInit<TestClass>(() => new TestClass(), LazyInitMode.EnsureSingleExecution);
```

One day I wanted to benefit all the new things that comes with .NET 4, installed it and hell breaks loose.

My LazyInit didnt work anymore. So i replaced every occurence with Lazy<T> but what about
`LazyInitMode.EnsureSingleExecution`?

I thought that would be `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`.

```
private static Lazy<LookupService> s_instance = new Lazy<LookupService>(() => new LookupService(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
```

Are these two declerations equivelant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Effectively, yes.  By setting `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`, you are saying that you only want a single thread to be able to construct the `Lazy<T>`, which is effectively "ensuring single execution" for the construction phase.  `PublicationOnly` will allow multiple threads to run the constructor, but only store one result (the first completed).